# how to detect click on annotation mapkit and run action

Tags: objective-c, annotations, mapkit

I create one app that have `mapkit` and I can to add specific annotations in my map and I want when to tap (click) on any annotation do one method or one action but I don't about it.

please guide me . I searching many time in google but don't give correct answer for my question.

this is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [self GetMyLocation];

    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)];
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
    mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I'm Here"];
    [mapView.userLocation setSubtitle:@"Rahnova Corpration"];
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
    [self addAnnonations];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressGesture:)];
    [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];

}
- (void) addAnnonations{

    NSArray *title = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Rome",@"Chelsea", nil];
    NSArray *subtitle = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Red",@"Blue", nil];
    NSArray *latitude = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"35.738000",@"35.739901", nil];
    NSArray *longitude = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"51.310029",@"51.312018", nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dictionary setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    [dictionary setObject:subtitle forKey:@"subtitle"];
    [dictionary setObject:latitude forKey:@"latitude"];
    [dictionary setObject:longitude forKey:@"longitude"];


    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        NSString *Name = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"title"]objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *SubName = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"subtitle"]objectAtIndex:i];
        double Lati = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"latitude"]objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
        double Long = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"longitude"]objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];

        [self SetTitle:Name SetSubtitle:SubName SetLatitude:Lati SetLongitude:Long];
    }
}

- (void) SetTitle:(NSString *)title SetSubtitle:(NSString *)subtitle SetLatitude:(double)latitude SetLongitude:(double)longitude{

    //create coordinate for use annotation
    CLLocationCoordinate2D annoLocation;
    annoLocation.latitude = latitude;
    annoLocation.longitude = longitude;

    Annotation *myAnnonation = [[Annotation alloc]init];
    myAnnonation.coordinate = annoLocation;
    myAnnonation.title = title;
    myAnnonation.subtitle = subtitle;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:myAnnonation];
}
- (void) centerLocation{
    //create region
    MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = latitudes;
    center.longitude = longitudes;

    //span
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
    span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;

    myRegion.center = center;
    myRegion.span = span;

    [mapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        longitudes = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        latitudes = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        [self centerLocation];
    }
}
#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dude try this :

[Xcode 4 iPhone SDK Tutorial - How to add different actions to each annotation-pin HD](http://youtube.com/watch?v=PBP0kKbJGk8)

or this :

[Detecting when MKAnnotation is selected in MKMapView](http://www.zenbrains.com/blog/en/2010/05/detectar-cuando-se-selecciona-una-anotacion-mkannotation-en-mapa-mkmapview/)